# A very evil cipher

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, story, no-computers

A very evil tyrant locks you in a very evil cellar in a very evil castle. Every day he brings you a bit of soup and a bit of bread with a message he says, "It's the code but you have to decipher it first"

It looks like this:

> 0250416262415026226078014170611222100254212090

Comment: I think this puzzle is cool. It's *another* cipher one but it's ok.

Comment: He bring you the message everyday?

Comment: i can't answer it if it has incorrect grammar

Comment: Ummm... I'm not locked in a cellar.

Comment: No computers. Interesting... that means it can't be a complex algorithm... Doesn't seem to fit with anything in the ASCII-Chart. Definitely not hexadecimal, nor octa, nor binary, nor decimal. Perhaps we're looking at homophonics...? I'm not too sure.

Comment: @North Also there are 46 letters so only possible groupings are 1 number or 2 numbers...23 isn't likely

Comment: @NL628 or use one letter as a key and you've got 45, much more possible groupings

Comment: @TinyTRex72 hint? ^-^

Comment: I'm getting soup and bread each day, how evil can he be?

Comment: i remember noticing on friday that broken off into pairs the first 8 are similar but reversed (almost): 02 50 41 62 
62 41 50 26

Comment: @Einb You're getting sawdust bread and worm turnip stew

Comment: @oMiKeY Could it be a form of cipher in which every 2 numbers is a letter?

Comment: Please clarify: What is `evil` about the cipher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Grammar is watching you

This must be a form of cipher where every 2 numbers is a specific letter:

> `02 50 41 62 62 41 50 26 22 60 78 01 41 70 61 12 22 10 02 54 21 20 90`
>  `1  2  3  4  4  3  2  5  6  7  8  9  3  10 11 12 6  13 1  14 15 16 17`

The `44` must be double letters. The most common double letters are SS, EE, OO, and TT. The letter 3 appears most, so it is likely an E. This rules out any vowel double letters, so it is TT or SS (Or other). Also, 5, 8, and 14 are the only letters with a ones digit greater than 2. Perhaps these are spaces? If so, you get

> `02 50 41 62 62 41 50    22 60    01 41 70 61 12 22 10 02    21 20 90`
>  `1  2  3  4  4  3  2     6  7     9  3  10 11 12 6  13 1     15 16 17`

A 7 letter word, 2 letter word, 8 letter word, and 3 letter word. Sounds pretty possible. The most common 2 letter words are of, to, in, it, is, be, as, at, so, we, he, by, or, on, do, if, me, my, up, an, go, no, us, am. The first word could be

> Presser or Grammar

So, as I expected, the 3 may be the letter

> E

or maybe

> A

If you use these letters, you get

> `02 50 41 62 62 41 50    22 60    01 41 70 61 12 22 10 02    21 20 90`
>  `p  r  e  s  s  e  r     6  7     9  e  10 11 12 6  13 1     15 16 17`

or

> `02 50 41 62 62 41 50    22 60    01 41 70 61 12 22 10 02    21 20 90`
>  `g  r  a  m  m  a  r     6  7     9  a  10 11 12 6  13 1     15 16 17`

It would make the most sense to say that the second word is

> is

So that would mean it is now

> `02 50 41 62 62 41 50    22 60    01 41 70 61 12 22 10 02    21 20 90`
>  `g  r  a  m  m  a  r     i  s     9  a  10 11 12 i  13 1     15 16 17`

or

> `02 50 41 62 62 41 50    22 60    01 41 70 61 12 22 10 02    21 20 90`
>  `p  r  e  s  s  e  r     i  s     9  e  10 11 12 i  13 1     15 16 17`

Now, let's look for a pattern:

> We know that no matter what, 50 is R. 22 is I, and 60 is S. R and S are 1 letter apart, yet the difference is 10. Coincidence? I think not. I think Grammar is a more sensible solution, so 41 is A, 62 is M, 02 is P.

I cannot find a pattern for the rest, but I'm looking hard.

Never mind...the pattern is

> Backwards! 41 backwards is 14. 62 backwards is 26. This means that it is instead
>  `20 05 14 26 26 14 05    22 06    10 14 07 16 21 22 01 20    21 02 09`
>  `g  r  a  m  m  a  r     i  s     9  a  10 11 12 i  13 1     15 16 17`

Because of this, I can assume

> that it is a Caeser Cipher

because

> The numbers are never above 26

So...

> It uses rot13

The answer is

> Grammar is watching you

Comment: Wait...just realized something!

Comment: I find your deductions intriguing, but ... what makes it evil, I wonder?

Comment: @IanMacDonald OP could have just meant evil in the sense that it is given to you while you're being held hostage, and can't escape until you  crack it

Answer (score 2):

> Interestingly, the quoted message (excluding apostrophe, including space) has the same length as the message:

Break for formatting

> `its the code but you have to decipher it first`
>  `0250416262415026226078014170611222100254212090`

Comment: That's a good observation, but note that the text had "decypher" in its original version. Meanwhile, the text has been updated, but the cipher has stayed the same.

Comment: Good point. Although I'd be curious if that change was intentional to correct the puzzle, rather than a simple typo fix.

Comment: I think this must be the solution, that's why it's very evil! Also thinking literally, it states it as well.

Comment: just a coincidece